# jQuery window.scroll move div vertical in opposite direction

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have a div that scrolls down on the page scroll and when I scroll up the div scrolls up. I would like the opposite

This is the code:

```
// SCROLL BUTTON
// -- iPhone picture should scroll in when down and down when up
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){   
        jQuery(".iphonepic").stop().animate({ "top": (jQuery(window).scrollTop() - 0.00) + "px"}, "slow"); 
    });
```

So when you scroll down, the div should go up vertically not the same as the scroll direction.

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/khaleelm/sQZ9G/7/

Update

I also want to limit the DIV not to go higher than -150px, trying

```
if ( parseInt(jQuery(".iphonepic").css("top"), 10) >= -150 ) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
{ top: -jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 'px' }
```

Also, a few tips to make it more efficient.

You're calling `jQuery(window)` and `jQuery('.iphonepic')` on every scroll event, that's really expensive. Just do:

```
var $window = jQuery(window), $iPhonePic = jQuery('.iphonepic')

$w.on('scroll', function(){

  var top = -$window.scrollTop();

  if ( top < -150 ) {
    top = -150;
  }

  $iPhonePic.stop().animate({
    top: top + 'px'
  }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Can I limit it. I do not want the top to ever go higher than -150px

Comment: I would set a variable called `top` and assign `-$window.scrollTop()` to it. If it's less than that, make it `-150`, else keep it the same. I'll update my answer.