# Reversing the scroll of a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I reverse the scroll function of my website such that when the user scrolls up, the page will scroll down in the opposite direction?

Comment: I don't think this is possible using scripts.  It's more a computer/mouse settings thing.

Comment: Why you want to tortuse yous users??

Comment: @laaposto .... "turtose"? http://www.google.ca/imgres?imgurl=https://facinatingamazinganimals.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/tortoiseturtle.jpg&imgrefurl=https://facinatingamazinganimals.wordpress.com/tortoise-versus-turtle/&h=205&w=246&tbnid=C6NKZdi06x9zbM:&zoom=1&tbnh=166&tbnw=200&usg=__UOs10Kd8JlePTWxHdD3yvFwX5u8=&docid=-O5mHzVamTAzmM&itg=1&ved=0CI4BEMo3&ei=D138VPn9CoLLsATy9oCoDA

Comment: I think it is possible because i've seen being implemented in the conduit website: http://conduit.com .

Comment: Conduit.com tracks the position of the scroll bar and offsets the right div accordingly. You are still scrolling down normally on the left div.

Comment: I guess this is resolved [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747576/jquery-window-scroll-move-div-vertical-in-opposite-direction

Comment: You can do this by creating a virtual scroll like others are doing

Comment: @DominatorX It's definitely possible using scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this for the entire page is going to give a very broken experience.

You'll wind up doing something like the following, where you find the height of your content, then start manually positioning it within a fixed viewport:

```js
var $window = $(window), $container, height;

$(function() {
  $container = $('#content');
  
  // Add some content
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    $container.append('<h1>line ' + i + '</h1>');
  }

  height = $container.outerHeight();
  $('body').css('height', height + 'px');
  
  // Set up scroll handling, but also invoke once to initialize positions
  $window.on('scroll', onScroll);
  onScroll();
});

function onScroll() {
  scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  $container.css('top', (scrollTop - height + $window.height()) + "px");
}
```

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;  
}

#viewport {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="viewport">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, `#viewport` remains fixed infront of the user, occupying the whole screen. The content scrolls backwards inside of `#viewport` while the HTML document scrolls normally.

Meanwhile, `#content` has a height of ~50,000px, which I read and apply directly to the document, so that there will be a scroll bar of the appropriate size even though `#content` is contained within `#viewport` which has a fixed height set to that of the window.

Then, on scroll, the actual content gets position so that it moves upwards by the same distance you've scrolled with `scrollTop`.