# On scroll, how to make a div in the background move up, while the div on top of it moves in the opposite direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the website: http://kingston20x15.com/

What jquery should I be looking at specifically to try and get the blocks in the background to move in the opposite direction vertically to the blocks in front of the text?

So far I've been trying to hack this fiddle unsuccessfully:

http://jsfiddle.net/5UUtV/1/

```
var winHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".panel").height(winHeight);
    $("body").height(winHeight*$(".panel").length);
});

$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    $(".panelCon").css('bottom',$(window).scrollTop()*-1);
});
```

Comment: is http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/ the effect you are looking for (activate the debug mode to see).

Comment: That's just moving the background in the same direction, but at a slower rate, correct? 

I'm trying to move the blocks in the background in the opposite direction to those in the foreground.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery window.scroll move div vertical in opposite direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747576/jquery-window-scroll-move-div-vertical-in-opposite-direction)